# real time log processing using apache spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, flume, spark-streaming

I want to create a system where I can read logs in real time, and use apache spark to process it. I am confused if I should use something like kafka or flume to pass the logs to spark stream or should I pass the logs using sockets. I have gone through a sample program in the spark streaming documentation- [Spark stream example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html). But I will be grateful if someone can guide me a better way to pass logs to spark stream. Its kind of a new turf to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache Flume may help to read the logs in real time.
Flume provides logs collection and transport to the application where Spark Streaming is used to analyze required information.

**1.** Download Apache Flume from [official site](https://flume.apache.org/download.html) or follow the instructions from [here](http://mapredit.blogspot.kr/2012/07/run-flume-13x-on-windows.html)

**2.** Setup and run Flume
   modify flume-conf.properties.template from the directory where Flume is installed (FLUME_INSTALLATION_PATH\conf), here you need to provide logs source, channel and sinks (output). More details about setup [here](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html)

There is an example of launching flume which collects log information from ping comand running on windows host and writes it to a file:

*flume-conf.properties*

```
agent.sources = seqGenSrc
agent.channels = memoryChannel
agent.sinks = loggerSink

agent.sources.seqGenSrc.type = exec
agent.sources.seqGenSrc.shell = powershell -Command

agent.sources.seqGenSrc.command = for() { ping google.com }

agent.sources.seqGenSrc.channels = memoryChannel

agent.sinks.loggerSink.type = file_roll

agent.sinks.loggerSink.channel = memoryChannel
agent.sinks.loggerSink.sink.directory = D:\\TMP\\flu\\
agent.sinks.loggerSink.serializer = text
agent.sinks.loggerSink.appendNewline = false
agent.sinks.loggerSink.rollInterval = 0

agent.channels.memoryChannel.type = memory
agent.channels.memoryChannel.capacity = 100
```

To run the example go to FLUME_INSTALLATION_PATH and execute

```
java -Xmx20m -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///%CD%\conf\log4j.properties -cp .\lib\* org.apache.flume.node.Application -f conf\flume-conf.properties -n agent
```

OR you may create your java application that has flume libraries in a classpath and call org.apache.flume.node.Application instance from the application passing corresponding arguments.

How to setup Flume to collect and transport logs?

You can use some script for gathering logs from the specified location

```
agent.sources.seqGenSrc.shell = powershell -Command
agent.sources.seqGenSrc.command = your script here
```

instead of windows script you also can launch java application (put 'java path_to_main_class arguments' in  field) which provides smart logs collection. For example, if the file is modified in real-time you can use [Tailer](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/Tailer.html) from Apache Commons IO.
To configure the Flume to transport the log infromation read this [article](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-flume-integration.html)

**3.** Get the Flume stream from your source code and analyze it with Spark.
Take a look on a code sample from github https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/JavaFlumeEventCount.java

Answer (score 3):

You can use Apache Kafka as queue system for your logs. The system that generated your logs e.g websever will send logs to Apache KAFKA. Then you can use apache storm or spark streaming library to read from KAFKA topic and process logs at real time.

You need to create stream of logs , which you can create using Apache Kakfa. There are integration available for kafka with storm and apache spark. both has its pros and cons.

For Storm Kafka Integration look [here](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2014/05/27/kafka-storm-integration-example-tutorial/)

For Apache Spark Kafka Integration take a look [here](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2014/10/01/kafka-spark-streaming-integration-example-tutorial/)

Answer (score -1):

Although this is a old question, posting a link from Databricks, which has a great step by step article for log analysis with Spark considering many areas.

https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-reference-applications/content/logs_analyzer/index.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please add some content from the link

Comment: Hi Robert,I am afraid it is a GitBook and has very good chapters to explain the underlying usecase for spark streaming with logs. Let me know if you are looking for something specifc, as this book covers most of it.